# Remove doubles isn't removing overlapping vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

As you can see, I have vertices on top of vertices, I'm trying to delete them using delete doubles but it says there are 0. But they're clearly overlapping perfectly. I set my merge distance to 0 but they still wont delete. I'd rather not manually delete all of them so if you guys could point out what I've done wrong please help.

[image]

Comment: Threshold at 0 effectively turns off any effect of the Remove Doubles operator. It should be set to something higher than default 0,001

Answer (score 3):

I didn't realize you needed to select vertices for remove doubles to have an effect. To remove doubles on the whole model, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> first (you may need to press it twice if you have anything selected beforehand).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share. I've taken the liberty of [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your answer to add some additional information. If you don't agree with my edits, please feel free to roll them back and/or edit some more.